# Ramanujan's curious cubic identities

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, cubics

Given the cubic,
$$z^3-ez^2+fz-1=0$$
Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be the three roots. Define,
$$x_n = z_1^{1/n}+ z_2^{1/n}+ z_3^{1/n}$$
$$y_n =  (z_1z_2)^{1/n}+ (z_1z_3)^{1/n}+(z_2z_3)^{1/n}$$
Ramanujan found that,
$$x_3^3-e = y_3^3-f= 3(x_3y_3-1) \tag{1}$$
$$ \frac{x_5^5-e}{x_5^2-y_5} = \frac{y_5^5-f}{y_5^2-x_5} = 5(x_5y_5-1) \tag{2}$$
$$ \frac{x_7^7-e}{(x_7^2-y_7)^2+x_7} = \frac{y_7^7-f}{(y_7^2-x_7)^2+y_7} = 7(x_7y_7-1) \tag{3}$$
He stops here, but is there a generalization to $p=11$,
$$ \frac{x_{11}^{11}-e}{P_1} = \frac{ y_{11}^{11}-f}{P_2} =11(x_{11}y_{11}-1) \tag{4}$$
where $P_1,P_2$ are polynomials in $x_{11},y_{11}$ analogous to the previous ones?

**P.S.** Just a remark. These relationships can be proven *after* knowing about it, but how in the world does Ramanujan come up with them *in the first place*?

Comment: Why do you assume this has something to do with $n$ prime, and not $n$ odd? It would seem to me to be about odd $n$, since then $z_i^{1/n}$ are roots of the equation $z^3-x_nz^2+y_nz-1$.

Comment: I was looking at the factorization of $(a+b+c)^p-(a^p+b^p+c^p)$. It  has the factor _p_ only for prime _p_.

Comment: Re: your **P.S.**: That statement can apply to nearly all of Ramanujan's results. :)

Comment: @anorton: Agreed. I think I just figured out how to answer my question though.

Comment: In which notebook was this result?

Comment: @IshanSingh: I already forgot. Might be in Berndt's Vol III.

Answer (score 2):

After staring at my question for a while, I realized how to answer it. Let,

$$a,b,c=z_1^{1/11}, z_2^{1/11}, z_3^{1/11}$$

hence (for convenience), $p=a+b+c=x_{11},\; q=ab+ac+bc=y_{11},\; abc = 1$. Then,
$$\frac{x_{11}^{11}-e}{P_1} = 11(x_{11}y_{11}-1)$$
is equivalent to,
$$(a+b+c)^{11}-(a^{11}+ b^{11}+ c^{11}) = 11(pq-1)\, P_1$$
Since $pq-1 = (a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ if $abc=1$, then all that remains is to express $P_1$ in terms of $p,q$. One finds that,
$$P_1 = (p^2 - q) (p^6 - 3 p^4 q + 4 p^2 q^2 - q^3) + p (3 p^2 - 5 q) (p^2 - q) + (2p^2 - q)$$
holds true if $abc=1$. For $P_2$, let $p,q\to q,p$.

I used *Mathematica* to find this, and the more complicated form is probably the reason why Ramanujan didn't include it in his Notebooks. Even though he didn't write "*...and so on*" indicating there were more identities, he probably did know.

P.S. I didn't check if it can be done for $n=9$, though as T. Andrews points out, it may work for odd *n*.